How to force Ubuntu to hold & force use kernel linux-image-6.5.x?
EDIT: 2024-08-18: DO NOT DO THIS/ASK for this
(see @guiverc answer below - he is right). Kernel 6.5 is end of life (no more security updates).
Currently supported Kernels: https://www.kernel.org/
I would like my Ubuntu 22.04 to keep using Kernel 6.5 and only let it update security updates on the 6.5 (ie keep updating to versions 6.5.0-45 then 6.5.0-46 and so on). I don't have any interest as of this moment in Kernel 6.8 as it causes heaps of trouble for me.
So far I did:
nano /etc/default/grub
changed GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
and set GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
(the default was GRUB_TIMEOUT=0)
This way every time I boot I have a chance to use Kernel 6.5 but it's manual and annoying.
What is the best way to make Ubuntu 22.04 to hold onto the Kernel 6.5 (with security updates) and not to upgrade to 6.8 until I manually say so?
I found this:
sudo apt-mark hold <package_name>      # stop upgrading
sudo apt-mark unhold <package_name>    # resume upgrading
somebody also recommended (with slight modification):
apt-mark hold linux-generic-hwe-22.04
But that won't work (I suppose?) as my apt list --installed | grep linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
already shows:
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Courtesy of: How to I prevent Ubuntu from kernel version upgrade and notification?
So I'm worried if I do sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic as listed the above it will force-hold the current version "linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic" and that it won't install any security updates. Maybe I'm wrong here.
I have unattended updates in place and I would like to have those updates to other software I simply want to have kernel left out.
Thank you all for your help.
The reason I want this:
I'm experiencing issues with VMWare Workstation and this year it's probably 3rd time I had to do weird hacks to just hold it together. I'm in process of switching to another virtualisation software (looking at VirtualBox) hopefully I will have better luck there.
Related topics:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773558/vmware-vmmon-vmnet-17-5-1-and-linux-kernel-6-8-0-wont-compile
https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/issues/250

There is no need to muck about with apt-pinning, apt-marking, or other haywiring. There's a fully-supported metapackage for exactly this use case. Simply look up how to change from an HWE kernel metapackage to a GA kernel metapackage.

There are NO MORE SECURITY UPDATES for 6.5, it was the kernel from 23.10 which is now EOL; thus 22.04 systems using the HWE kernel stack moved to 6.8 from 24.04 LTS which will get security fixes into the future.  Ubuntu 22.04 had various kernel stack options; HWE only stayed on stacks from non-LTS for ~six months (6.5 from 23,10, 6.2 from 23.04, 5.19 from 22.10) as per kernel docs; why not consider an alternate kernel stack such as GA which does still get security fixes rather than an unsupported and now unpatched kernel??  Your question makes wrong assumptions.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  and yes if you pin to an EOL kernel you won't get security updates for that kernel; Ubuntu 23.10 is EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/)

Thank you guys - I updated my OP.
What is the best way to switch to Kernel 6.6 (seems to be one of those LTS versions) and lock the system to keep using it and not to upgrade further?

Don't forget if you switch off a Ubuntu provided kernel (ie. 22.04 has multiple supported kernels; GA = 5.15, HWE is now 6.8, OEM = ...) you won't get security patches automatically provided by Ubuntu; but you'll need to manage that yourself (given you've installed a kernel from 3rd party or testing source). Unless the installer used a OEM kernel, the GA or HWE are the safest options.

So how do I switch to GA 5.15 or similar older LTS while maintaining the future updates within the apt update && apt dist-upgrade command and without any 3rd party ppa repositories?

In the link I provided on LTSEnablementStack I'd suggest reading the section after "To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:" if you want to switch from a HWE (or OEM) kernel to GA as it specifically covers LTS releases which is why I provided it.  Both GA + HWE (plus OEM) can co-exist on an all open source install; however do note some third party (closed source) kernel modules (eg. some NVIDIA) can prevent multiple kernel stacks from co-existing on an install.  You just select at boot (ie. grub) which you'll use (ie. this is just doing the testing the doc suggests without uninstall step)
